# I need to print a 2D graph using Slashes and Pipe symbols " / \ | " in Python

Tags: python, arrays, list, for-loop, graph

Here is the instructions to print the 2D graph

> 1. The user will input a word.
> 2. For the alphabets a to z, numbers from 1 to 26 will be assigned for each alphabet starting from ‘a’ i.e,
>    (a=1,b=2,c=3,d=4,e=5,........,y=25,z=26)
> 3. If the input word is "aejz" then then the list that should be generated for the graph will look like this[1,5,10,26]
> 4. If the letter is a consonant then the line has to go up (using /) incrementing till it reaches its positional value(a=1,....,z=26) and
>    if it is vowel then the graph will come down (using ) decrementing
>    till it reaches its positional value.
> 5. If the previous letter and the current letter are consonants then there will be a gap created using two pipes(|), one above another. And
>    also if the previous letter and the current letter are both vowels
>    then there will also be a gap created using two pipes, one below
>    another.
> 6. Man like symbol will be created for the highest peak.
>
> Sample Input and Output: [Sample
> 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t2UeY.png), [Sample
> 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yboh4.png), [Sample
> 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VaPeS.png)

Here is what I have done
I have tried to collect the word as input and converted it to the respective numbers i.e a=1, b=2,..z=26.

```
alpha=["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"]
usr_input=str(input("Enter the strings: "))
usr_input=usr_input.lower()
for l in usr_input:
    if l in alpha:
        num=(alpha.index(l)+1)
        data.append(num)
```

And then for the purpose of check are the given numbers are vowels or not I have used a if condition

```
for i in data:
    if i==1 or i==5 or i==9 or i==15 or i==21:
        print("\\"*i)
    else:
       print("/"*i)
```

And then I got stuck I can't able to print the result as in graph format and then I cannot able to fit the pipe(|) symbol when If the previous letter and the current letter are consonants and then printing the man symbol at the highest peak

Here is the code to print the man, but I don't know how to place it in the highest peak

```
print(' \u25cb',"\n/|\\\n< >")
```

The whole progress I did after posting it to the SO

```
    #Getting words from users and coverting it to numbers
data=[]  
alpha=["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"]
usr_input=str(input("Enter the strings: "))
usr_input=usr_input.lower()
for l in usr_input:
    if l in alpha:
        num=(alpha.index(l)+1)
        data.append(num)
vow=[1, 5, 9, 15, 21]
#operations
final=[]
max_column=sum(data)
for i in range(max_column):
    final.append([" "] * (max_column*2))
    final.append([" "] * (max_column*2))


def graph(data):
    x,y=0,0
    tmp=[]
    for i,j in enumerate(data):
        tmp.append(j)
        
        if j not in vow:
            for _ in range(j):
                final[x][y]="\\"
                x+=1
                y+=1
            
        else:
    
            for _ in range(j):
                x-=1
                final[x][y]="/"
                y+=1
               
            


graph(data)

for res in final:                   
    print("".join(res))
```

Output: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EZLzh.png)

Comment: Interesting problem. Class assignment?

Comment: That was a fun exercise.  I have a solution but since this sounds like homework I'll give advice.  Use a dictionary to track the row/column as key and character as a value.  Plot it out virtually using the dictionary, then you can query that dictionary for the max rows and columns needed for you 2D graph.  Then allocate it and plot it.  Make an honest attempt and add it to your question and I'll post my solution.

Comment: @MarkTolonen I hope I did what you said

Comment: It's a start, but needs to handle the vertical bars.  Try entering the input in your samples and account for that.

Comment: @MarkTolonen It is actually a online based assessment organized in a company for internship interview, I need it to submit in within today itself

Comment: @MarkRansom Nope

Comment: Good to know, then it would be unethical to post my code for you or for you to use it

Comment: @MarkTolonen I don't agree, I am a beginner of python I asked to other friends who are having high skills in python and working as python developer they can't able to answer it

Comment: The assessment is of *your* skills not mine or your friends.  How far you can get with it on your own is how the company assesses you.

Comment: @MarkTolonen I have solved the assessment successfully.